# Understanding Interfaces vs Objects in API

Tags: vba, solidworks

So I've been using the API for Solidworks quite a bit at work to write very simple VBA scripts for task automation. It's been really helpful, but to say I'm not a programmer is a huge understatement. The thing I'm currently struggling with is why everything in the API seems to have an I in front of its name.

The API reference is [here](http://help.solidworks.com/2013/English/api/SWHelp_List.html?id=c64d3add5f4443bba1a7070ab6358873#Pg0) and everything is preceded by an I. It seems to work as well or better if I just declare things for instance as Sldworks.ModelDoc2 rather than IModelDoc2 as the API says. I've googled this quite a bit, and it seems to have something to do with interfaces vs. objects, but I'm not fully understanding the distinction. I feel like I'm missing something really obvious, but it hasn't come to me yet.

Can anyone shed some light on what the I's are doing, and why things seem to work fine without them?

**Edit:** As a follow up, I ended up finding [this](http://help.solidworks.com/2012/english/api/sldworksapiprogguide/OVERVIEW/In-process_Methods.htm), which explains what the I was doing in the Solidworks API. It seems like it isn't exactly related to interfaces after all.

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of articles which can explain the difference between objects and interfaces, but my understanding is that it boils down to this: Interfaces separate behavior from implementation. In many cases, this is used to allow dissimilar objects to be used collectively for a similar purpose. For example, you might have `Car`, `Bike`, `Truck`, `Boat`, `Train` and `Bus` classes which are all very different, but if they all implement an `ITransportation` interface with a single method called `transport(person, destination)`, I don't have to care about the underlying differences to move people around.

In this case, though, I suspect that the interface is being used for future backwards compatibility. Suppose that 10-15 years down the road Solidworks is up to `ModelDoc34`. If your code is expecting the same set of properties and functions as `ModelDoc2`, you would more than likely be disappointed. However, suppose that `ModelDoc34` implements the `IModelDoc2` interface - that is, the developers provide a limited set of the new functionality that matches exactly the set of properties and functions of the old `ModelDoc2` class to allow your code to still be able to run, as long as you reference the new class name. In a similar vein as the earlier analogy, imagine it's 50 years into the future. Cars no longer have any manual controls, you just punch in your destination and away it goes. If the developers wanted to make this car backwards compatible, they could implement the `IStandardCar` interface which would include things like gas/brake pedals and a steering wheel.

If you want to write your code to be as future-proof as possible, you would declare your variables to be of type `IModelDoc2`. Let the Solidworks API do the work of figuring out what the underlying object type will be and you can write your code as if it was always just a `ModelDoc2`.

Comment: Thanks, that's super helpful. I've been reading a bit about objects vs interfaces, and your examples are really helpful, but somehow it's still not quite coming into focus. I think it's largely due to my shaky knowledge of object oriented languages in general. I'm also having trouble finding almost any objects at all in the API that I'm looking at. Maybe that's intentional for the reasons that you're mentioning.

Comment: I don't have Solidworks, but my guess is that the objects are exposed as a single hierarchy. There would be the Solidworks parent object and all the other objects would be levels of children below it.

Comment: @JamesPettit In Excel for example, you can create Shapes. Suppose I created a circle on the default Sheet1 of the Excel workbook through the Insert ribbon tab. I would then reference it in code by `Excel.Sheets(1).Shapes(1)`. You couldn't simply write `Dim thing as Shape; Set thing = new Shape` to create a new shape because shapes must have an existence on a particular worksheet - they can't exist in an abstract sense. Instead, you would have to let the hierarchy create it for you, automatically associating it with a parent object: `Excel.Sheet(1).Shapes.AddShape()`